# Downloading attachment based on time sent, using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have VBA code for "downloading mail attachment based on sender name".

Sometimes the sender will send multiple files in a day.

I want to download the first file sent, based on time of sending.

What changes to be done in the code in this case?

```vb
Sub DATA()
Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Object 'Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Object 'Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim at As Object 'Outlook.Attachment
Dim fso As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim dir As Object 'Scripting.Folder
Dim dirName As String
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim f As Integer
' change 1
Dim inboxFol As Object 'Outlook.Folder
Dim subFol As Object 'Outlook.Folder

'Some Set Ups
Set fso = CreateObject(Class:="Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ol = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' change 2
Set inboxFol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox
Set subFol = inboxFol.Folders("Operation")

'Finding the search item from Oulook Inbox
For Each i In inboxFol.Items
If i.Class = 43 Then
Set mi = i
If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 And InStr(mi.SenderName, "Ahmed") Then
dirName = "C:\Work Area"
If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
Else
Set dir = fso.Createfolder(dirName)
End If

'Saving Attachment to a folder
For Each at In mi.Attachments
If Right(at.Filename, 4) = "xlsm" Then
at.SaveAsFile dir.Path & "\" & "Daily Work Data.xlsm"

End If
Next at
' change 4
mi.UnRead = False
mi.Move subFol
End If
End If
Next i

'Setting Folder
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Work Area")

CreateObject("shell.application").Open ("C:\Work Area\Daily Work data.xlsm")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the first file sent today.

```vb
Sub DATA()

Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim Ns As Object 'Outlook.Namespace
Dim i As Object

Dim mi As Object 'Outlook.MailItem

Dim inboxFol As Object 'Outlook.Folder
Dim colItems As Object 'Outlook.Items

Dim strFilter As String
Dim resItems As Object

Set ol = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
Set Ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxFol = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox

Set colItems = inboxFol.Items
colItems.Sort "[SentOn]", False ' oldest to newest

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senton
strFilter = "[SentOn]>'" & Format(Date, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"
Debug.Print "strFilter .....: " & strFilter

 ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict
Set resItems = colItems.Restrict(strFilter)
Debug.Print "resItems.Count: " & resItems.Count

If resItems.Count Then

    For Each i In resItems
        If i.Class = 43 Then
            Set mi = i
            'If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 And InStr(mi.SenderName, "Ahmed") Then
                Debug.Print "Subject.....: " & mi.subject
                Debug.Print "SentOn .....: " & mi.SentOn
                mi.Display
                Exit For ' Exit when the first is found
            'End If
        End If
    Next i

Else

    Debug.Print "no items found."
    
End If

End Sub
```